# Emacs not loading package at startup

Tags: emacs, package, startup

Emacs will not load the package `window-number` I have the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
;;;windows                                                                  
(require 'window-number)                                                    
(window-number-mode)
```

However, once emacs is started if I type: `M-x load-file RETURN .emacs`
Then `window-number-mode` will be loaded.

What is going on here and why won't `window-number` load on startup? Note that I downloaded `window-number` from elpa

**EDIT** window-number-mode works, but it won't start when emacs starts. I have to type `M-x window-number-mode`. I tried inserting `(window-number-mode)` into my `.emacs` file but this did not fix my problem.

Comment: Have you tried using (window-number-mode 1) as the documentation suggests? (note the difference to what you're doing, which is without the 1)

Answer (score 2):

If you loaded the package from elpa, make sure you have `(package-initialize)` before you use the package.  That function (among other things) updates the load-path to include the directories of downloaded packages.

The "require" might be unnecessary, as elpa packages typically have autoloads, but it makes no harm.

Comment: what do you mean by `(package-initialize)`

Comment: This is an elisp function, just like window-number-mode.  Just put that before the `(require 'window-number)`

Answer (score 1):

In .el file have you seen this?

```
;; Installation
;; ============

;; Drop this file into your load path.  C-h v load-path RET or F1 v
;; load-path RET will help.  Then place the following lines into your
;; .emacs or ~/.xemacs/init.el and uncomment them.

;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

;; (autoload 'window-number-mode "window-number"
;;   "A global minor mode that enables selection of windows according to
;; numbers with the C-x C-j prefix.  Another mode,
;; `window-number-meta-mode' enables the use of the M- prefix."
;;   t)

;; (autoload 'window-number-meta-mode "window-number"
;;   "A global minor mode that enables use of the M- prefix to select
;; windows, use `window-number-mode' to display the window numbers in
;; the mode-line."
;;   t)

;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

;; Then you can use M-x window-number-mode RET to turn the mode on, or
;; place (window-number-mode 1) and (window-number-meta-mode 1) into
;; your .emacs or ~/.xemacs/init.el.
```

Comment: It works, just not automatically. How do I get window-number-mode started when emacs starts?